# How to set an item in ComboBox to "SelectedText" property of ComboBox dynamically in Load

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In WinForm, I have a ComboBox. I am trying to do something like this.

When ComboBox has only 1 item, that item should be set as "Selected Text" for ComboBox,
and when it has items more than 1, first item should be set as "Selected Text".

I want this to be happened at the time of Form Load.

how can i do this?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: SelectedText will get the text of the item that is selected. And a ComboBox by default will select the first item anyway. As it stands, I can't understand how you don't already have this working automatically. Are you trying to say you have two controls involved in this? Your question doesn't make much sense to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it the right way, you want the first item of the combobox to be selected/shown in comboBox.

This is quite easy:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //This will select the first item in the combobox (zero based numbering)
```

To set it right after the form is shown simply put it after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

of the appropriate form.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
if (ComboBox1.Items.Count>0) { ComboBox1.SelectedIndex=0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if combobox has only one item, then you can use below code

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex =0;
```

if combobox has multiple item, and you need to select a particular item...
change only the index, index will start with 0, if you need to show second item, then the index will be 1

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex =1;
```